# Can I coerce a lifetime parameter to a shorter lifetime (soundly) even in the presence of `&mut T`?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm trying to make a tree with parent pointers in Rust. A method on the node struct is giving me lifetime issues. Here's a minimal example, with lifetimes written explicitly so that I can understand them:

```rust
use core::mem::transmute;

pub struct LogNode<'n>(Option<&'n mut LogNode<'n>>);

impl<'n> LogNode<'n> {
    pub fn child<'a>(self: &'a mut LogNode<'n>) -> LogNode<'a> {
        LogNode(Some(self))
    }

    pub fn transmuted_child<'a>(self: &'a mut LogNode<'n>) -> LogNode<'a> {
        unsafe {
            LogNode(Some(
                transmute::<&'a mut LogNode<'n>, &'a mut LogNode<'a>>(self)
            ))
        }
    }
}
```

([Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=45df254c0c58399a7eb5dca0ba13f009))

Rust complains about `child`...

> error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter `'n` due to conflicting requirements

...but it's fine with `transmuted_child`.

I think I understand why `child` won't compile: the `self` parameter's type is `&'a mut LogNode<'n>` but the child node contains an `&'a mut LogNode<'a>`, and Rust doesn't want to coerce `LogNode<'n>` to `LogNode<'a>`. If I change the mutable references to shared references, [it compiles fine](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5a7ff9d3f3c3350b9f56944eb3ab3343), so it sounds like the mutable references are a problem specifically because `&mut T` is invariant over `T` (whereas `&T` is covariant). I guess the mutable reference in `LogNode` bubbles up to make `LogNode` itself invariant over its lifetime parameter.

But I don't understand why that's true—intuitively it feels like it's perfectly sound to take `LogNode<'n>` and shorten its contents' lifetimes by turning it into a `LogNode<'a>`. Since no lifetime is made longer, no value can be accessed past its lifetime, and I can't think of any other unsound behavior that could happen.

`transmuted_child` avoids the lifetime issue because it sidesteps the borrow checker, but I don't know if the use of unsafe Rust is sound, and even if it is, I'd prefer to use safe Rust if possible. Can I?

I can think of three possible answers to this question:

1. `child` can be implemented entirely in safe Rust, and here's how.
2. `child` cannot be implemented entirely in safe Rust, but `transmuted_child` is sound.
3. `child` cannot be implemented entirely in safe Rust, and `transmuted_child` is unsound.

Edit 1: Fixed a claim that `&mut T` is invariant over the lifetime of the reference. (Wasn't reading the nomicon right.)

Edit 2: Fixed my first edit summary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is #3: `child` cannot be implemented in safe Rust, and `transmuted_child` is unsound¹. Here's a program that uses `transmuted_child` (and no other `unsafe` code) to cause a segfault:

```
fn oops(arg: &mut LogNode<'static>) {
    let mut short = LogNode(None);
    let mut child = arg.transmuted_child();
    if let Some(ref mut arg) = child.0 {
        arg.0 = Some(&mut short);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut node = LogNode(None);
    oops(&mut node);
    println!("{:?}", node);
}
```

`short` is a short-lived local variable, but since you can use `transmuted_child` to shorten the lifetime parameter of the `LogNode`, you can stuff a reference to `short` inside a `LogNode` that should be `'static`. When `oops` returns, the reference is no longer valid, and trying to access it causes undefined behavior (segfaulting, for me).

---

¹ There is some subtlety to this. It is true that `transmuted_child` *itself* does not have undefined behavior, but because it makes other code such as `oops` possible, calling or exposing it may make your interface unsound. To expose this function as part of a safe API, you must take great care to not expose other functionality that would let a user write something like `oops`. If you cannot do that, and you cannot avoid writing `transmuted_child`, it should be made an `unsafe fn`.

Answer (score 5):

To understand why the immutable version works and the mutable version is unsound (as written), we have to discuss [subtyping and variance](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/subtyping.html).

Rust mostly doesn't have subtyping. Values typically have a unique type. One place where Rust *does* have subtyping, however, is with lifetimes. If `'a: 'b` (read `'a` is longer than `'b`), then, for example, `&'a T` is a subtype of `&'b T`, intuitively because longer lifetimes can be treated as if they were shorter.

Variance is how subtyping propagates. If `A` is a subtype of `B`, and we have a generic type `Foo<T>`, `Foo<A>` might be a subtype of `Foo<B>`, vice versa, or neither. In the first case, where the direction of subtyping stays the same, `Foo<T>` is said to be covariant with respect to `T`. In the second case, where the direction reverses, it's said to be contravariant, and in the third case, it's said to be invariant.

For this case, the relevant types are `&'a T` and `&'a mut T`. Both are covariant in `'a` (so references with longer lifetimes can be coerced to references with shorter lifetimes). `&'a T` is covariant in `T`, but `&'a mut T` is *invariant* in `T`.

The reason for this is explained in the Nomicon (linked above), so I'll just show you the (somewhat simplified) example given there. Trentcl's code is a working example of what goes wrong if `&'a mut T` is covariant in `T`.

```
fn evil_feeder(pet: &mut Animal) {
    let spike: Dog = ...;

    // `pet` is an Animal, and Dog is a subtype of Animal,
    // so this should be fine, right..?
    *pet = spike;
}

fn main() {
    let mut mr_snuggles: Cat = ...;
    evil_feeder(&mut mr_snuggles);  // Replaces mr_snuggles with a Dog
    mr_snuggles.meow();             // OH NO, MEOWING DOG!
}
```

---

So why does the immutable version of `child` work, but not the mutable version? In the immutable version, `LogNode` contains an immutable reference to a `LogNode`, so by covariance in both the lifetime and the type parameter, `LogNode` is covariant in its lifetime parameter. If `'a: 'b`, then `LogNode<'a>` is a subtype of `LogNode<'b>`.

We have `self: &'a LogNode<'n>`, which implies `'n: 'a` (otherwise this borrow would outlast the data in `LogNode<'n>`). Thus, since `LogNode` is covariant, `LogNode<'n>` is a subtype of `LogNode<'a>`. Furthermore, covariance in immutable references again allows `&'a LogNode<'n>` to be a subtype of `&'a LogNode<'a>`. Thus, `self: &'a LogNode<'n>` can be coerced to `&'a LogNode<'a>` as needed for the return type in `child`.

For the mutable version, `LogNode<'n>` isn't covariant in `'n`. The variance here comes down to the variance of `&'n mut LogNode<'n>`. But since there's a lifetime in the "`T`" part of the mutable reference here, the invariance of mutable references (in `T`) implies that this must also be invariant.

This all combines to show that `self: &'a mut LogNode<'n>` can't be coerced to `&'a mut LogNode<'a>`. So the function doesn't compile.

---

One solution to this is to add the lifetime bound `'a: 'n`, though as noted above, we already have `'n: 'a`, so this forces the two lifetimes to be equal. That may or may not work with the rest of your code, so take it with a grain of salt.

Comment: I accepted trentcl's answer because it helped me realize how to solve my problem, but your answer is super helpful too! Thanks for putting your explanation in terms of my code.